# How to install and use pgAgent for postgres

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, pgagent

I have downloaded separately pgagent 3.4.1 & pgAdmin 4. I want to create jobs from inside pgAdmin like explained  https://www.openscg.com/bigsql/docs/pgadmin4/pgagent_install.html but when I execute the command I get the error : 
`ERROR: could not open extension control file "E:/Program Files (x86)/PostgreSQL/9.6/share/extension/pgagent.control": No such file or directory
SQL state: 58P01`. Is there any link that gives details how to install & use pgAgent from inside pgAdmin 4?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is very easy if you will use the EnterpriseDB GUI installers.

1) Download & Install PostgreSQL-9.6(standard) from installers provided by EnterpriseDB

[Download link](https://www.enterprisedb.com/software-downloads-postgres)

2) Open Stack builder from Menu -> Choose the Postgres server you want to install pgAgent on from the list

[image]

[image]

3) Now select pgAgent and click Next to install and follow the steps.

[image]

4) Restart pgAdmin4 and you will be able to see the pgAgent option in the browser window tree.

(I am using pgAdmin4 rc build so ICONS may looks different)

[image]

Comment: so...we must uninstall/reinstall using an unusual EnterpriseDB installer?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I already had PostgreSQL 9.6 installed but did not have start menu folder for the program. But I was able to start the stackbuilder.exe from the folder: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin. Rest, I followed the instructions and saw "pgAgent Jobs". I was just curious to see if pgAgent had advanced job chaining with dependencies but it does not seem like that's the case.